# Alternate screen buffer for the Windows console

Tags: python, windows, windows-console

I'm looking for a way to switch to an alternate screen buffer in the Windows console. I know how it works for terminals that support ANSI escape sequences, i.e. simply shoving `\033[?1049h` or `\033[?1049l` to stdout for switching to the secondary/primary buffer respectively. But I was wondering how one could accomplish something similar in the Windows console.

The following contextmanager is how I would intend to use this feature in my code:

```py
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def alt_buffer():
    try:
        print("\033[?1049h\033[22;0;0t\033[0;0H", end="")
        yield
    finally:
        print("\033[?1049l\033[23;0;0t", end="")
```

Comment: Does `cmd.exe` even have multiple buffers? I thought it was a "one page" kind of thing? You probably have to soft wrap this and create your own buffers and store/switch context. I might be wrong because I've never needed this in Windows, but I've also never heard of it - so I can only assume `cmd.exe` (and `powershell.exe` lack anything called double buffers. They have buffer size but that's only for the current window). Only thing you can do is `mode con:cols=140 lines=70` for instance to change the current buffer size IIRC.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking the same kind of thing, but I was wondering how some other projects achieve something similar. I stumbled on a version of less that works on windows¹, and it seems that the windows api has tooling for this...

1: https://github.com/adoxa/less/blob/master/screen.c#L1491-L1529

Comment: Additionally the magical windows terminal project actually supports the proper ANSI escape sequences¹...

1: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences#alternate-screen-buffer

Comment: Ah, It looks like they're [creating their own software buffer](https://github.com/adoxa/less/blob/master/screen.c#L1506-L1509) that isn't handled by underlaying API's. And they're storing the original buffer history in a "original" variable to later re-print it or something. Quickly glanced at the code and might be wrong.

Comment: Yeah seems so, but I'm unsure to replicate this in python or if I should even try...

Comment: Run `reg query "HKCU\Console" -v VirtualTerminalLevel`. Returns `1` if  ANSI escape sequences are enabled, otherwise returns `0` or _ERROR: The system was unable to find …_.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea! I'll have to try it once I get the time to. 

Comment: But yes, the `cmd.exe` does support VT100-esk control sequences, altho not all that I'm aware of. And they're a bit buggy from past experiences and very individual if it works, probably because of what JosefZ said.

Comment: You create a buffer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/createconsolescreenbuffer then switch to it https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsoleactivescreenbuffer

Comment: I updated the question to refer to the Windows console. CMD is a shell that uses standard I/O, not a console or terminal. As of Windows 7, each console session, which may or may not create a window and is a good deal more than just the UI in the window, is hosted by an instance of conhost.exe. Prior to Windows 7, each console session was hosted by the Windows session server, csrss.exe, but for security they moved console sessions into separate processes. In the new Windows 10 terminal (wt.exe), console sessions are hosted by an open-source fork of conhost.exe named OpenConsole.exe.

Comment: In the Windows console API, a new screen buffer is created via [`CreateConsoleScreenBufffer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/createconsolescreenbuffer), and the active screen buffer can be set via [`SetConsoleActiveScreenBuffer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsoleactivescreenbuffer).

Comment: Regard ANSI escape sequences, the new console in Windows 10 supports them, but unless "VirtualTerminalLevel" is set in the registry, as mentioned above, they have to be manually enabled via `GetConsoleMode` (to get the current mode) and [`SetConsoleMode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolemode) with the `ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING` flag set in the mode. If you need ANSI support in older Windows versions, you'll have to look to alternate consoles such as ConEmu or ANSICON, which work in part by injecting a DLL in processes that hooks (hacks) the API.

Comment: Eryk Sun this question was specifically on if this behavior was something achievable in CMD, not if it was possible in [Windows Terminal](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal) as that was already considered as fact. Instead of editing the question a simple answer would have been more appreciated. And additionally, this is something that my question didn't make clear properly, i wish to do this from **python** without having to writing a platform specific cpython-extension...

Answer (score 0):

Hey I know that this question is years old at this point, but the trick here is to make sure to manually request "Virtual Terminal" mode in the console. This is done by setting the `ENABLE_VT_PROCESSING` flag in a call to `SetConsoleMode`.

I've got a blob of python I use [here](https://github.com/zadjii/win-py-vt/blob/master/enable.py) that looks like this:

```py
# Turns VT output support on
def enable_vt_support():
    if os.name == 'nt':
        import ctypes
        hOut = ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetStdHandle(-11)
        out_modes = ctypes.c_uint32()
        ENABLE_VT_PROCESSING = ctypes.c_uint32(0x0004)
        # ctypes.addressof()
        ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetConsoleMode(hOut, ctypes.byref(out_modes))
        out_modes = ctypes.c_uint32(out_modes.value | 0x0004)
        ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetConsoleMode(hOut, out_modes)
```

You don't *need* to do this for Windows Terminal, because that launches processes with that flag set by default. But for the broadest set of compatibility, it's always a good idea to just set that at the start of your process when you know you're gonna be emitting VT sequences.

The Alternate Screen Buffer is supported in the console going back to RS2, which I think is Windows 10 build 15063.